# I need an application to read aloud any emails that come into a specific email address

Tags: email, applescript, audio, server.app, voice

I want a sort of audio server which sits in background (running on OS X, not iOS) and whenever an email arrives at a specific address, it reads it aloud. Ideally there would be also an option to filter by a "password" so that spam doesn't get read aloud.  I have a home automation system that can send notification emails when stuff happens, and since I already have computers throughout the house, I'd like to have them announce the events rather than buying dedicated audio output client hardware.  I'm hoping I can cobble something together with existing software and system tools to enable my Macs to act like audio endpoints (addressed via email).

Any ideas?

Comment: In Mail look at the rules that apply when it receives a new Mail - one option is to filter on who receives it then play an Applescript. The script could be made to read the email

Comment: I see how to make it run a script, but how do I get the Applescript to get passed (from Mail) the text for it to read?

Answer (score 1):

As Mark mentioned, AppleScript is the way to go here:

Create a mail rule that runs the following script when an email from your home automation system is received.

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages theselectedMessages
    tell application "Mail"
        repeat with a_message in theselectedMessages
            set the_sender to extract name from sender of a_message
            if (junk mail status of a_message) is not true then
                tell me to say "Mail from " & the_sender
                tell me to say (get content of a_message)
                set read status of a_message to true
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```